# Два джоина к одному запросу

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть запрос. К нему мне нужно приджоинить ещё две выборки и в результате получить

```
ЗАПРОС_A джоин ЗАПРОС_B
+
ЗАПРОС_A джоин ЗАПРОС_C
```

Можно это как то сделать в одном запросе? или нужно сложить результаты двух запросов?

Comment: Приджойнить или объединить? Нужны результаты обоих запросов в одной выборке - используйте Union, нужно пересечение - делайте оба джойна в одном запросе

Comment: "приджоинить" это выполнить нормальный join что бы записи из первой выборки как то соотносились с записями из второй (что делается просто несколькими join подряд) или что бы записи второй выборки были как бы под записями из первой, что делается с помощью UNION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ЗАПРОС_A джоин ЗАПРОС_B
UNION ALL
ЗАПРОС_A джоин ЗАПРОС_C
```